# runtime type checking with haskell / cabal / stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

In a Haskell project, I am using a dependency which I know contains type error. But that's actually fine as I never call this code.

So I want to enable  `defer-type-errors` but ***only for that dependent package***.

Is there a way to scope that compiler instruction somewhere (stack ? cabal?)

Comment: Wouldn't fixing the package be a better solution...?

Comment: sure, but that's like saying we don't need defer-type-errors

Comment: and actually in that case, there is no type error per se. it compiles fine with ghc, but ghcjs maps to some other primitive type unfortunately

Comment: GHCJS maps replace CTime with HTYPE_TIME_T (https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-boot/blob/master/boot/base/Foreign/C/Types.hs) and maps this symbol to Int32 (https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/blob/master/include/HsBaseConfig.h) whereas ghc maps to Int64

Comment: ideally we'd have no error etc.. but since I dont use that code anyway, the escape latch would be useful, if it's not a general one

Comment: If you really have to you can [set ghc options per package in `stack.yaml`](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/yaml_configuration.md#ghc-options). I'm not sure whether it's compatible with ghcjs.

Comment: @nicolas I think it's different than saying we don't need `-fdefer-type-errors`: that flag can be a useful tool during development without ever once appearing in a production system.

Comment: @DanielWagner and that can be useful here too. I know I don't use the problematic library. Fixing some constant deep in the guts of GHCJS with potentially rippling consequences for something I dont use is of little benefit

Comment: @DanielWagner I agree that the burden of proof is too big for me to claim that this equate to saying we dont need defer-type-error in every scenario you might use it for. my bad :)

Comment: @zakyggaps can you put that as an answer. that's a useful setting to know about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to you can [set ghc options per package in stack.yaml](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/yaml_configuration.md#ghc-options), namely:

```
ghc-options:
    your_package_name: -fdefer-type-errors
```

I'm not sure whether it's compatible with ghcjs.

But please be sure to make the users of your package aware, maybe include a disclaimer in the document in **big bold fonts**.